# Can't print fields in a view template

Tags: views, theming

I'm overriding drupal /blog path with a views. Created a new view page display and set path to blog. Created views-view-unformatted--blog-page.tpl and trying to output view fields this way:

```
<?php 
print $fields['title']->content;
print $fields['body']->content;
?>
```

But all what i get is nothing, tried to output `<?php print 'Hello, world!'; ?`> == it outputs Hello,world. But i can't print Views fields...

PS in another view display - printing fields this way works perfectly. Blank fields affects only blog page view display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template you have overwritten looks like this (in Drupal 6):

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div class="<?php print $classes[$id]; ?>">
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

As you can see, it's purely used to print out the rows in the view; you should instead use one of the other templates available, if you want to alter the fields. Take a look at the theming information button in the UI that will give you a complete list with previews.

Comment: Oh, god. You're right, thanks! Worked all day and now im not attentive :(